# Sorting and exporting in/from Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, csv

Im quite new to scripting and I have a big database to sort. These are the steps I want to make

1. Sort my data on the first column bij filtering on a specific list. The data consists of measurements. The first column represents the measurement-number. Each point measured has an own row with the distance and height specified in columns b and c. In the .xlsx I have, all the measurements are put together.
2. Exporting the sorted measurement-numbers to seperate .csv files.

This an example of my data, here I have 2 measurements represented by the numbers 608800 and 610530. I want to write all the records for both measurements in two seperate .csv files.

```
608800  -2195,90421622  0,808
608800  -2194,93193587  0,803
608800  -2193,95556312  0,788
608800  -2193,07734816  0,834
608800  -2192,19411721  0,958
608800  -2191,04093680  0,94
608800  -2190,08414372  0,955
608800  -2188,94860063  0,965
608800  -2187,81928020  0,965
610530  142,16756501    -0,248
610530  142,02441644    -0,188
610530  136,54007522    -0,05
610530  126,20777287    0,42
610530  115,94287198    0,978
610530  106,43471929    1,706
610530  101,91716011    2,222
610530  92,70524860 2,431
```

I hope anyone knows a good solution, thanks in advance!

Vincent

Comment: How have you tried solving the problem yourself? What challenges are you facing?
Asking someone else to do your work is different than asking for help in solving a problem. Request you to go through Stack Overflow Tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the response. I'm quite new into this world and I'm looking for an example, because I can't find any online yet. I know it sounds a bit lazy, but I don't have the time to dive into it completely right now.

Comment: Right now I know the following: I need xlrd to sort my Excel and xlwt to write the separate files. Can anyone help me with the code?